# What's the best way to convert an arbitrary string into a readable dice roll result?

Tags: python, string, dice

I am quite new to python coding.

My code is written that only keeps character "0-9", "+", "-", "*", "/" and "d".
An example input would be  *"3d6 + 4d3 + 3d2 - 433 seffesfes"*
Which would resolve into *"3d6+4d3+3d2-433"*. I was informed that using the eval() function is a bad idea, so I am not sure the best way to perform the final calculation would be.

I considered looping through the string until it finds something that isn't numeric, then going backwards to find the first half, then second half, then perform the function based on what it found - but this doesn't seem right.

Comment: have you tried a regex?

Comment: I think i wasn't clear, it uses  dice_input = re.sub('[^0-9d\+\-\*\/]', '', dice_input) already, I want to know how to convert "3d8" into random.randint(1, dice_faces) for each part of the string.

Comment: first explain what you mean with `3d8`, and what does `433` mean

Comment: "3d8" means roll 3 8-sided dice. Essentially, I want to convert "XdY" strings into just a number, then perform the calculation on the whole string, supporting the ability to add, subtract (such as subtract 433), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex, we can eliminate every character that doesn't match your accepted character list and strip your string:

```
import re

re.sub("[^\d+\-*\/d]", '', your_str)
```

Example:

```
import re

re.sub("[^\d+\-*\/d]", '', "3d6 + 4d3 + 3d2 - 433 seffesfes")
# >>> '3d6+4d3+3d2-433'
```

Regex explanation:

```
Match a single character not present in the list below [^\d+\-*\/d]:
    \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    + matches the character + literally (case sensitive)
    \- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
    * matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
    \/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
    d matches the character d literally (case sensitive)
```

You can learn more on regex (and play with that regex) here: https://regex101.com

**EDIT:**

After we have parsed your initial string, to do a proper evaluation of the random value, you should use `re.sub`:

```
import re
import random

def roll(match):
     a,b = match.group(1).split('d')
     return str(random.randint(int(a), int(a)*int(b)))

re.sub('(\d+d\d+)', roll, your_parsed_string)
```

**Explanation:**
`re.sub` is a function that receives a regex pattern to find in a given string and then replace it with an alternative value. but this function also supports a replace from a callback, which is the `roll` function that is passed to the `re.sub`.

the callback function receives as a parameter the `re.Match` object and as a result has access to all of its traits. one of those is the method `group` which let us access the groups that were parsed by our regex (regex groups are marked by `()` and let us access parts inside our captured regex easily).

So, we capture every appearance of a dice roll, send it to the callback function `roll` as a regex match, and then parse that stringed value to the "roll dice" that you desire to acheive.

**For example:**

```
your_parsed_string = '3d6+4d3+3d2-433'
re.sub('(\d+d\d+)', roll, your_parsed_string)
# >>> '8+9+2-433'
```

Now, to safely evaluate the final string, use something like: https://github.com/pydata/numexpr

Or - write a simple parsing function yourself

Comment: You don't need to escape `+`, `*` and `/`.

Comment: I think i wasn't clear, it uses dice_input = re.sub('[^0-9d\+\-*\/]', '', dice_input) already, I want to know how to convert "3d8" into random.randint(1, dice_faces) for each part of the string.

Comment: @VisioN It is not probably, it is, inside `[]` only `\` has special meaning and needs to be escaped. `]` if put as first character inside `[]` does not need an escape. `[^]]` should be valid

Comment: @LewisMcMeekin I'll edit my answer in 2 minutes with some more regex magic

Comment: @rioV8 There is no special meaning for these characters inside a character class.

Comment: @VisioN Bad formatting and not re-reading, only `\` has special meaning. `]` if put as first character inside `[]` does not need an escape. `[^]]` should be valid

Comment: Could you explain how this works? I don't want to just copy-paste it in without knowing.

Comment: @LewisMcMeekin I'll explain in the answer, one second

Comment: @LewisMcMeekin Updated my answer with an explanation, please give it a look again.

Comment: I have implemented the solution, but "3d6" has spat out a 2, which is impossible to throw on 3 dice, as the minimal result is 3. I assume return "str(random.randint(1, int(a)*int(b)))" should be return str(random.randint(1, int(b)) and a loop to add each amount.
To clarify, does this work on numbers greater than 1 character? For example does 34d56+4d3 pick up 34 and 56, then 4 and 3 separately?

Comment: @LewisMcMeekin Oops, fixed that - look at my answer now, in the implementation of roll, the first parameter given to random.randint is now `a` instead of `1` as this is the minimal number a roll of `a` dices could yield.

Comment: @LewisMcMeekin Also Yes, it would work for any number of dices and any number of faces as my regex pass `\d+` (which request any number between 0 to 9 and at least 1 repeat of that)

Comment: raise ValueError("non-integer arg 1 for randrange()")
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()

This doesn't happen if you replace a with 1 from your previous version

Comment: @LewisMcMeekin fixed again, look at the original answer, I just had to parse a to int.

Comment: This has been exceptionally helpful. I think I can work out any further code from here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replace function in the `re.sub` to convert your dice notation into numbers.

```
def convertDice(matchobj):
    faceCount = int(matchobj.group('faces'))
    return str(sum(random.randint(1, faceCount) for _ in int(matchobj.group('times')) ))

re.sub(r"(?P<times>\d+)d(?P<faces>\d+)", convertDice, your_str)
```

Now you have a string that can be evaluated

Comment: Could you explain how this works? I don't want to just copy-paste it in without knowing.